# AngularJS - textarea placeholder not showing while in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, textarea, angular-ui-bootstrap

So I found out that if I use `<textarea placeholder="Write something.."></textarea>` inside `ng-repeat`, the placeholder of the textarea only shows on focus.
If I remove the `ng-repeat` of my parent element then my placeholder appears on page load.

Same result if I use something like `<textarea name="{{repeat.id}}">`

text inputs are working fine.

I'm using angularJS 1.3.0-beta.17 and ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0

Any information on that?

**Update:**
I found out that if I set a `ng-model`, then the placeholder shows correctly.